# Unable to make work both private and public ip network on openvz container in Proxmox

Tags: networking, debian, vlan, proxmox, hosting

I'm using Proxmox 3, it is a fresh installation. For those who know, I'm using OVH Vrack 1.5 (along with a previous Vrack 1.0).

My server has two interface eth0 and eth1, I succeeded to configure both private and public ip on the host node, and I'm able to ping all my server on the vlan.

Now, I created an OpenVZ container, and I assign both a public and private ip in the Proxmox GUI (simple venet).

Let's say I use 172.16.0.129 for the internal network.

Once I login in the container, I'm able to successfully ping all my **private** network but I'm not able to reach any public ip.

Here is the host node configuration:

`ifconfig`

```
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8a:ee:41:c1:ec:53
          inet6 addr: fe80::84ed:41ff:fec1:ec53/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1950 (1.9 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:32:90:a7:43:48
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:111570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:140197486 (133.7 MiB)  TX bytes:8647245 (8.2 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:54:43:49
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:43258 (42.2 KiB)  TX bytes:6322 (6.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2507778 (2.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2507778 (2.3 MiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/128 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3535 (3.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2236 (2.1 KiB)

vmbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:a7:43:48
          inet addr:5.135.14.28 Bcast:5.135.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:103047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:137374926 (131.0 MiB)  TX bytes:6823790 (6.5 MiB)

vmbr1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 86:ed:41:c1:ec:53
          inet6 addr: fe80::84ed:41ff:fec1:ec53/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

vmbr2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:a7:43:49
          inet addr:172.16.0.128  Bcast:172.31.255.255  Mask:255.240.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fea7:4349/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:30789 (30.0 KiB)  TX bytes:4794 (4.6 KiB)
```

`interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# for Routing
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
    post-up /etc/pve/kvm-networking.sh
    bridge_ports dummy0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0


# vmbr0: Bridging. Make sure to use only MAC adresses that were assigned to you.
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 5.135.14.28
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 5.135.14.0
    broadcast 5.135.14.255
    gateway 5.135.14.254
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

# bridge vrack 1.5
auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
    address   172.16.0.128
    netmask   255.240.0.0
    broadcast 172.31.255.255
    gateway   172.31.255.254
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_stp   off
    bridge_fd    0
```

And the routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.0.129    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
4.1.5.13        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
5.135.14.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 vmbr2
0.0.0.0         5.135.14.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
```

The container routing table is the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

and `ifconfig`

```
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:252 (252.0 B)  TX bytes:1594 (1.5 KB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:172.16.0.129  P-t-P:172.16.0.129  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:4.1.5.173  P-t-P:4.1.5.173  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

To resume:

- from the host I'm able to reach both public and private network.
- from the container I'm able to reach either the public **or** the private network depending on the order I assign ip addresses.

I compared to some existing Proxmox configuration which works great but I was not able to find any diffs.

Any help will be **greatly** appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the related forum topic over at the Proxmox site - http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/5008-Network-issue-setting-up-two-networks-(OpenVZ-container)

You need to use VETH (bridged) networking not the default venet(routed) networking.

Create 2 bridged interfaces via the Proxmox gui (one for each bridge interface/network), then you can configure 2 network interfaces inside the container like you would do any other type of server, 1 for each network

for more information on the differences between venet and veth - take a look at the openvz wiki - http://openvz.org/Differences_between_venet_and_veth